# How to count occurences in several date ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, count, date-range

I'm able to do a query to get the number of customers who comes in a shop from age 18 to 24 per month and per shop.
I'm doing it like this:

```
select year, month, shop_id, count(birthday) 
from customers 
where birthday 
BETWEEN '1992-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1998-01-01 00:00:00'
group by year, month, shop_id;
```

Now, I'm having an issue making this query for several ranges at the same time.

I have currently this database schema:

```
shop_id | birthday | year | month |
--------+----------+------+--------
 567   | 1998-10-10 | 2014 | 10 |
 567   | 1996-10-10 | 2014 | 10 |
 567   | 1985-10-10 | 2014 | 10 |
 234   | 1990-10-10 | 2014 | 10 |
 123   | 1970-01-10 | 2014 | 10 |
 123   | 1974-01-10 | 2014 | 11 |
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
shop_id | year | month | 18 < age < 25 | 26 < age < 35
--------+------+-------+---------------+-------------
567   |  2014  | 10    | 2             | 1
234   |  2014  | 10    | 1             | 0
123   |  2014  | 10    | 0             | 0
```

In the first query, it does not manage the case where one shop has NO customers. How to get 0 if there is not?

How to query the several date ranges at the same time?

Comment: Have case expressions in the select list, one for each age group. E.g. `, count(case when ... then 1 end) as 18_age_25, count(case when ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filters, use case statements:

```
select year, month, shop_id, 
count(case when birthday between <range1> then 1 end) RANGE1,
count(case when birthday between <range2> then 1 end) RANGE2,
count(case when birthday between <range3> then 1 end) RANGE3
from customers 
group by year, month, shop_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

"No rows with zeros" is a common problem with `GROUP BY` queries. The solution is to make your `FROM` be whatever table has the complete list, and then do a `LEFT JOIN`. Since you are grouping by year and month too, you'll need to produce the complete list of years and months. You can do that with `generate_series`:

```
SELECT  t.t, s.id, COUNT(c.birthday) 
FROM    shops s
CROSS JOIN generate_series('2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:00:00', interval '1 month') t(t)
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c
ON      c.shop_id = s.id
AND     c.birthday 
        BETWEEN '1992-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1998-01-01 00:00:00'
AND     c.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.t)
AND     c.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.t)
GROUP BY t.t, s.id
ORDER BY s.id, t.t;
```

To get counts for two date ranges, you could do what @mo2 suggests, or you could join to the `customers` table twice:

```
SELECT  t.t, s.id, COUNT(DISTINCT c1.id), COUNT(DISTINCT c2.id) 
FROM    shops s
CROSS JOIN generate_series('2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:00:00', interval '1 month') t(t)
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c1
ON      c1.shop_id = s.id
AND     c1.birthday 
        BETWEEN '1992-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1998-01-01 00:00:00'
AND     c1.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.t)
AND     c1.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.t)
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c2
ON      c2.shop_id = s.id
AND     c2.birthday 
        BETWEEN '1982-01-01 00:00:00' AND '1992-01-01 00:00:00'
AND     c2.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.t)
AND     c2.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.t)
GROUP BY t.t, s.id
ORDER BY s.id, t.t;
```

Note that in both queries I am `SELECT`ing a full datetime rather than `year` and `month`. That is more flexible I think, but it should be easy to change if you want.

**EDIT:** I realized your `year` and `month` are not birthday-related, but something else, I guess the visit date? So I updated my query. If you are only checking one month at a time, you could remove the `generate_series` and just put the year and month integers directly into the join conditions.